# What old language is this?

Tags: programming-languages

A friend of mine sended bunch of code for me to build a software. However, I do not recognize language and my friend is no coder. One thing I'm sure about though. The code is something like 20-40 years old.

Code was originally used in electrical works.

Character limit per line seems to be 20 characters.

Can someone recognize this language? I'm also looking for manuals for this language if possible.

```
10:"K": PAUSE "IK": 
   CLEAR
15:P=1: INPUT "ETR=PRIN
   T, 0=NO? ";P
20:DIM L(20),R(20),X(20
   ),B(1),G(1),Q(1),O$(
   1)*24
22:IF P=1 INPUT "K. /DA
   TE? ";O$(0)
24:IF P=0 GOTO 30
26:INPUT "N:0 AND NAME?
   "; O$(1)
28:LPRINT O$(1): LPRINT 
   "KKS/";OS(0)
30:INPUT "(KVA)? ";S
35:IF P=1 LPRINT "KVA",
   S
40:R=3.31 :Z=4
...
```

I searched for this language and PowerBasic seems to be close to it, but it contains many  other features what this code lacks. Any guesses?

**Edit 1**

It seems that there were typos. No wonder "P=!" or "0$(0) didn't make any sense.

**Edit 2**

I accepted Gaby's answer because code seems to be very close to GW-Basic. Also found a manual for the language which works perfectly: http://www.antonis.de/qbebooks/gwbasman/

Thanks for the help!

**Edit 3**

Got some new information. Language might actually be something called "Nova Basic" from 1975. I'm unable to find manual for that language, but at least this gives me a new direction.

Comment: "it contains many other features..." Would it be possible that this code just doesn't use the other features?

Comment: Looks like BASIC to me

Comment: Mraok, it's _definitely_ not GWBASIC. That would barf on the first line since `"K"` is not a valid statement and it has no `PAUSE` keyword. In addition, the `DIM O$(1)*24` is not valid syntax either. If it, as you say, "works perfectly", I'd be rather circumspect about your testing methodology :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I didn't say that it works perfectly. I just assumed that the code works since it was used to calculate things. :P Language might actually be something called Nova Basic. Also machine that used it might have been something like "Decwriter III, LA120-GA" (irrelevant, kinda). I'll keep researching if I can figure out that "K".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's definitely a BASIC variant, one of those like in the early micro-computer days, before things like VB and structured coding came into play :-)

However, it has a few non-recognisable aspects such as:

- the statement `"K"`.
- the assignment `P=!`, unless that `!` should be a `1`.
- the use of variables starting with a numeric: `0$(0)`, unless you've mistakenly typed an `O` (owe) in as a `0` (zero).

None of those were very common in BASICs of the day though keep in mind the language wasn't standardised to the same level as something like C is nowadays. Everything else seems pretty standard: input, printing, assignment, array dimensioning, and so on.

Given the line length limit, the domain (KKS and KVA are both electrical terms) and the weird syntax variations, I'd say it was for one of the early programmable calculators, such as Casio, Texas Instruments or Sharp (though not *necessarily* those specific brands).

Comment: I believe `!` means to treat it a single precision variable.

Comment: @Gaby, yes, but that would be along the lines of `P!=0` specifying the type of `P`. Having the `!` on the right side of an assignment is nothing I've seen in any BASIC.

Comment: It seems that P=! was typo because line "IF P=! INPUT ..." would make no sense. I guess it was sticky shift key. Also GW-Basic that @GabyakaG.Petrioli suggested seems very close.

Answer (score 1):

It reminds me of [GW-BASIC](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/GW-BASIC)

Example code at http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/GW-BASIC

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot information in your code. Maybe `QBASIC` ? http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic